# AutoCompleteText не сохраняет меню выпадающего списка

Tags: java, android

Есть фрагмент, в котором AutoCompleteText используется для выпадающего списка. При переходе из  этого фрагмента в другой фрагмент и обратно, выпадающий список сокращается до одного элемента, который был выбран.

```
private AutoCompleteTextView dropModules;
private static String[] percents = {"25 %", "26 %", "27 %", "28 %", "29 %", "30 %"};

        btOpenLight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //кнопка для перехода в другой фрагмент
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("firstbody", String.valueOf(tmpCast * 0.1*1000));
            bundle.putString("secondbody", String.valueOf(tmpCast * 0.2*1000));
            bundle.putString("aromabody", String.valueOf(tmpCast * 0.05*1000));
            bundle.putString("heavybody", String.valueOf(tmpCast * 0.025*1000));
            Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(R.id.lightFragment, bundle);
        }
    });
    btOpenHeavy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //кнопка для перехода в другой фрагмент
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("firstbody", String.valueOf(tmpCast * 0.1*1000));
            bundle.putString("secondbody", String.valueOf(tmpCast * 0.2*1000));
            bundle.putString("aromabody", String.valueOf(tmpCast * 0.05*1000));
            bundle.putString("heavybody", String.valueOf(tmpCast * 0.025*1000));
            Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(R.id.heavyFragment, bundle);
        }
    });

    dropModules=root.findViewById(R.id.dropdown_perc1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterDrop = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, percents);
    adapterDrop.getFilter().filter(null); //если убрать, то выпадающий список будет состоять из 1 элемента
    dropModules.setAdapter(adapterDrop);
    dropModules.setText(dropModules.getAdapter().getItem(5).toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил вот так

```
        @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterDrop = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, percents);
        dropModules.setAdapter(adapterDrop);
        dropModules.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
```